# is there some lipsum package for formulae?

Tags: math-mode, lipsum

As I'm testing differents fonts (with LuaLaTeX) for my personal sty file, I use a doc with no sense texts and... formulae. I use `lipsum` package to generate text but I can't find an analog package to generate math-mode text (no-sense formulae)? Is there any?

Comment: Can you use the [`blindtext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext?lang=en) package? Use the option `math` and then you have access to `\blindmathpaper`.

Comment: @oliversm Great! Exactly what I was looking for! Thx.

Comment: @david: Note that the text from `\blindmathpaper`, e.g., will be in Latin unless you use `babel` or `polyglossia` to declare another language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `duckuments` package has a `maths` option. But the contained formulae as of now are really just two and simple ones:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\blindduck[maths]
\end{document}
```

[image]